# Python Script to read through lines of text in a file and count increases in numbers

Tags: python

I'm working on advent of code 2021 day 1 and the goal is to write code that will count each time a number in a file increases compared to the number before it if I interpreted the instructions correctly (I'm a beginner programmer)

I tried running this code

```
increases = 0
previous_number = float('-inf')  

with open('day 1 test input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        number = int(line)
        if number > previous_number:
            increases += 1
        previous_number = number

print(increases)
```

I had it read this input

```
199 
200 
208 
210 
200 
207 
240 
269 
260 
263
```

Instead of returning 7 like it should it returned 8. Any ideas as to why? Thank you!

Comment: It is 7. How did you get 8?

Comment: @drum By running it?

Comment: Did you intend to always count the first number as an increase ?  That could be the extra 1 that's being counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting an extra "increase" because `199` is greater than your initial value of `-inf`

Per user @KellyBundy, changing `float('-inf')` to `float('inf')` (positive infinity) should take care of this issue

```
increases = 0
previous_number = float('inf')  

with open('day 1 test input.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        number = int(line)
        if number > previous_number:
            increases += 1
        previous_number = number

print(increases)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have Python 3.10 you could use the pairwise function from the itertools module.  It will return pairs containing each item and its successor.  You can use that directly in a sum() to get your total number of increases:

```
from itertools import pairwise

with open('day 1 test input.txt') as file:
    increases = sum(a<b for a,b in pairwise(map(int,file)))
    
print(increases) # 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative naive approach:

```
increases = 0

with open('day 1 test input.txt') as file:
    for i in range(len(lines := file.readlines())-1):
        increases += lines[i] < lines[i+1]

print(increases)
```